# Somar os resultados de Count

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e no caso tenho a seguinte Consulta em SQL(SQL Server), a consulta é a seguinte

```
USE REPORT 
GO

SELECT TOP 10

  r.[PONTO DE ATENDIMENTO] , 
  r.[CIRCUITO], 
  count (t.co_ocorrencia) as Oscilações  

    FROM [dbo].[report_sirea] r 

        INNER JOIN [dbo].[report_ocorrencia_auxiliar] t ON t.co_ocorrencia = r.[co_ocorrencia] 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[planta_circuitos] p ON r.[CIRCUITO] = p.[DESIGNACAO]

         WHERE r.[INICIO] BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-22 23:59:59' 
         AND r.[OPERADORA] = 'FOR'
         AND r.[FECHAMENTO OCORRÊNCIA] IS NOT NULL AND r.[GITEC] = 'GITEC/FO' 
         AND p.[TIPO_CIRCUITO] = 'REDE 2' 
         AND r.[GRUPO] = 'Operadora' 

    GROUP BY r.[GITEC], r.[CGC], r.[PONTO DE ATENDIMENTO], 
        r.[CIRCUITO],  
        t.co_ocorrencia ORDER BY Oscilações DESC
```

No caso ela está trazendo o seguinte resultado

```
PONTO DE ATENDIMENTO | CIRCUITO       | Oscilações
PAE AAAAA            |LSR-VPN-F-91510 |     12
PAE BBBBB            |PNA-VPN-F-91512 |     12
AG. CCCCC            |PCR-VPN-F-91700 |     7
AG. DDDDD            |CHI-VPN-F-91692 |     4
AG. EEEEE            |JFT-VPN-F-130464|     4
AG. FFFFF            |PDZ-VPN-R-91590 |     4
AG. GGGGG            |BLA-VPN-F-91736 |     3
AG. HHHHH            |RSI-VPN-F-91716 |     3
AG. IIIII            |JFT-VPN-F-130464|     3
AG. CCCCC            |PCR-VPN-F-91700 |     3
```

No caso, a AG. CCCCC repete duas vezes dando 7 e 3 Oscilações. No caso, eu preciso que o resultado de Oscilações da AG. CCCCC sejam somados para atingir o 10, no caso, teria como? Ou precisaria fazer a codificação na linguagem que estou utilizando(PHP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está errando na hora de efetuar agrupamento, nesta parte do script:

```
GROUP BY r.[GITEC], r.[CGC], r.[PONTO DE ATENDIMENTO], 
        r.[CIRCUITO],  
        t.co_ocorrencia ORDER BY Oscilações DESC
```

você está informando que os resultados devem ser agrupados pelo número de ocorrências (t.co_ocorrencia) , e creio que você não precise disso, então para que retorne o resultado esperado é só remover o 't.co_ocorrencia' do 'GROUP BY':

```
GROUP BY r.[GITEC], r.[CGC], r.[PONTO DE ATENDIMENTO], 
            r.[CIRCUITO]
ORDER BY Oscilações DESC
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, agora deu certo!